# How to return the length of a contiguous subarray with specific criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm tasked with creating an array that takes another array and returns the number of contiguous subarrays for each index that fulfills the following conditions:

-The value at index i is the maximum value of the subarray
-The contiguous subarray must begin or end with i

I'm almost there but I'm missing the code to ensure that the function checks the array elements that aren't sat directly either side of i (see my code below). I think I might need some sort of recursive call that runs the if statement again while passing through the updated values of 'forward' and 'backward'. Or maybe I'm taking the wrong approach altogether.

Any ideas?

```
function countSubarrays(arr){
  var arr = [3, 4, 1, 6, 2];
  var output = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var total = 1;
    var forward = 1;
    var backward = 1;

    if (arr[i] >= arr[i+forward]) {
      total++;
      forward++;
      // Some sort of recursive call here?
    }

    if (arr[i] >= arr[i-backward]){
      total++;
      backward++;
      // Some sort of recursive call here?
    }

    output.push(total);
  }
  console.log(output);
}

countSubarrays();
```

Comment: Can you share some example like input and expected outputs in the question as well!

Comment: Sure, so I've hardcoded the original array in [3, 4, 1, 6, 2], and the expected output should be [1, 3, 1, 5, 1], but my current output is [1, 3, 1, 3, 1] because my function doesn't yet compare i with array elements that aren't directly next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go backwards or ahead and count the items who are smaller or equal to the actual element.

```js
function countSubarrays(array) {
    var output = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let value = array[i],
            total = 1;
            j = i;
        while (j-- && value >= array[j]) total++;
        j = i;
        while (++j < array.length && value >= array[j]) total++;
        output.push(total);
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(countSubarrays([3, 4, 1, 6, 2]));
```